"Please use the navigate() function" error with custom navigator
I have a custom navigator so some of my Fragments aren't recreated every time I navigate to them:

@Navigator.Name("keep_state_fragment")
class KeepStateNavigator(
    private val context: Context,
    private val manager: FragmentManager,
    private val containerId: Int
) : FragmentNavigator(context, manager, containerId) {

    override fun navigate(
        destination: Destination,
        args: Bundle?,
        navOptions: NavOptions?,
        navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras?
    ): NavDestination? {
        // destination tag
        val tag = destination.id.toString()

        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

        var initialNavigate = false
        val currentFragment = manager.primaryNavigationFragment

        if (currentFragment != null) {
            transaction.hide(currentFragment)
        } else {
            initialNavigate = true
        }

        var fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
        if (fragment == null) {
            val className = destination.className
            fragment = manager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(context.classLoader, className)
            transaction.add(containerId, fragment, tag)
        } else {
            transaction.show(fragment)
        }

        transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment)

        transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)
        transaction.commitNow()

        return if (initialNavigate) {
            destination
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}

I updated my navigation dependencies from:
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

to:
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7'

and I started getting this crash as soon as I try to navigate to any of these Fragments:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The fragment RadomFragment{ba44716} (dc8670e4-bec6-4649-8fc0-e3eeb066a5c9 id=0x7f0a048e tag=db2ba8d2-caf0-4c72-a7a9-6fc1154e7b67) is unknown to the FragmentNavigator. Please use the navigate() function to add fragments to the FragmentNavigator managed FragmentManager.
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$onAttach$2.onBackStackChangeCommitted(FragmentNavigator.kt:199)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1918)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8913)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

Is there something I can do? Or Google just decide to deprecate custom navigators?

Why are you extending FragmentNavigator? Your code already doesn't handle popping the back stack properly, much less want or need any of the other behavior that you are accidentally getting by extending FragmentNavigator.

@ianhanniballake sry, not sure what part of "I have a custom navigator so my fragments aren't recreated all the time" isn't clear. I have a specific situation in which I cannot rely on my view models to hold the state, so I need to prevent the navigation controller from destroying and recreating my fragments.
google "keep_state_fragment" on github and you will find plenty of other projects doing the same thing, it isn't ideal, but again, I have a special case here that goes beyond the scope of this question.

That's not what I said at all. I asked why your custom navigator extends FragmentNavigator.

@ianhanniballake what other class am i supposed to extend from if i want to implement a custom navigator?

Usually, you extend Navigator if you want to write a custom navigator.
